# How to get a property with get/set to serialize with JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have the following scenario:

```
var msp = function () { 
  this.val = 0.00;
  this.disc = 0;

};
Object.defineProperty(msp.prototype, "x", {
                        get: function () {return this.val - this.disc;},
                        toJSON: function () {return this.val - this.disc;},
                        enumerable: true,
                        configurable: true
                    });
var mp = new msp();
JSON.stringify(mp); // only returns {"val":0,"disc":0}
```

I was hoping that I can somehow set a toJSON method on the property "x" in the defineProperty call, but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
var obj = function() {
    this.val = 10.0;
    this.disc = 1.5;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        test: {
            get: function() { return this.val - this.disc; },
            enumerable: true
        }
    });    
};

var o = new obj;
o.test;
8.5
JSON.stringify(o);   // output: {"val":10,"disc":1.5,"test":8.5}
```

Note **test** is not a prototype definition and enumerable *has* to be set to **true**.

I tested the above **working** version in IE9, FF 11 and Chrome 18 - all three gave expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to apply it to the object itself not its prototype like this

```
var msp = function () { 
  this.val = 0.00;
  this.disc = 0;

};
msp.prototype.dif=function () {this.x = this.val - this.disc;return this;}

var mp = new msp();
JSON.stringify(mp.dif());
```

However if you are trying to serialize the function that is impossible.

Comment: no, that's not quite right, I need to serialize the whole instance of msp object (mp). so I want to get back {"val":0, "disc":0, "x":0} x of course being the difference between val and disc (if val = 10 and disc = 1 then x should be 9) but the point is that I need all three variables serialized.

Comment: @mspisars Ok well check this out to understand what the toJSON does https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior.  I'll update my answer to I think the only way to get what you want.

Comment: @mspisars I edited the answer.  I'm not sure that is what you want, but it will return what you want.

Comment: I got it to work... if I defined the properties like this

`var obj = function() {
    this.val = 10.0;
    this.disc = 1.5;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        "test": {
             "get": function() { return this.val - this.disc; },
             "enumerable": true
        }
    });    
};

var o = new obj;
o.test; // 8.5
JSON.stringify(o);
"{"val":10,"disc":1.5,"test":8.5}"`
note it is *not* a prototype definition and enumerable *has to be* set to *true*.
Thanks for all your help.
Michael